# Java - Unordered List methods for ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, unordered

I'm wondering what the methods for an UnorderedList for an ArrayList would look like. I know we would have addToFront, addToRear, and addAfter (all with T elements), but I've only ever seen this implemented with an array (see below). Is it possible to use an ArrayList instead? How would this change the methods? Hope my question makes sense.

This is the code I've come across:

```
public void addToFront(T element) {

    if (size() == list.length) {
        expandCapacity();
    }

    for (int i = this.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        this.list[i] = this.list[i-1];
    }

    this.list[0] = element;
    this.rear++;
}

/**
 * Adds the specified element to the rear of this list.
 *
 * @param element  the element to be added to the list
 */
public void addToRear(T element) {
    if (size() == list.length) {
        expandCapacity();
    }

    this.list[rear] = element;
    this.rear++;
}

/**
 * Adds the specified element after the specified target element.
 * Throws an ElementNotFoundException if the target is not found.
 *
 * @param element  the element to be added after the target element
 * @param target   the target that the element is to be added after
 */
public void addAfter(T element, T target) {
    if (size() == list.length) {
        expandCapacity();
    }

    int scan = 0;
    while (scan < rear && !target.equals(list[scan])) {
        scan++;
    }

    if (scan == rear) {
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("list");
    }

    scan++;
    for (int scan2 = rear; scan2 > scan; scan2--) {
        list[scan2] = list[scan2 - 1];
    }

    list[scan] = element;
    rear++;
}
}
```

Comment: Not much. Just give it a try. Few built-in representation used in your code might change.

Comment: @nullpointer When it comes to expanding capacity, would that be necessary for an ArrayList? My knowledge might be limited, but doesn't its capacity grow automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList abstracts the size management aspects of transitional Arrays. Check out:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test<T> {
  ArrayList<T> yourArray;

  Test() {
    // Initialize to avoid NPEs
    yourArray = new ArrayList<T>();
  }

  public void addToFront(T element) {
    yourArray.add(0, element);
  }

  public void addToRear(T element) {
     yourArray.add(yourArray.size(), element);
  }

  public void addAfter(T element, T target) {
     yourArray.add(yourArray.indexOf(target) + 1, element);
  }

  public void addBefore(T element, T target) {
     final int location = yourArray.indexOf(target);

     if (location == 0) {
       addToFront(element);
     } else {
       yourArray.add(yourArray.indexOf(target) - 1, element);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I guess I should brush up on my ArrayList methods. I forgot that it can shift the contents to the right by simply adding an element to the first index.